# setting up database connections between 3 tables in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

i can't seem to find a straight forward answer so let me explain what i'm trying to do with my example:

I'm trying to connect 3 tables together, i have `Users` `Artists` and `Events`

Now what im trying to do is make a huge spiderweb here, the plan is to have the user follow the artist and/or event.

The artist `belongs to` an event (there can be many artists to an event)

This is where i start to get confused. How do i go about making this work so that the user is connected to the event/artist depending on who/what they follow? (this is done in the view, the user goes to the event page and can click a `stay updated` button which would then save either the eventid or artist id to be used later.

What i don't get is,

What columns do i need to make in the database,

What do i need to do to the models to link them all together?

All my models are currently empty.

Comment: Have a look at the rails guides for associations (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html). It will explain the different types in detail and also provide the necessary code and migrations to set up the database and models.

Comment: Can an artist belong to multiple events?

Comment: Yes, an artist can belong to multiple events and multiple artists can belong to one event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a `has_many :through` association. The [Rails Associations guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) is very detailed on this topic, so check it out for an in-depth explanation.

Let's start with the `Artists` and `Events` tables.

An artist can play at many events, and an event will have many artists. To implement this relation a third table called `EventArtists` which keeps track of which events have which artists is needed, and which artists play at which events.

You can have multiple artists for one event (EventID 1), and a repeating artist (ArtistID 1) participating at multiple events.

**EXAMPLE:**

```
EventsArtists 
-----------------
ArtistID EventID
1        1
2        1
1        2
```

Your EventArtists will have a minimum of the two columns listed in the table above, which are `ArtistID` and `EventID`.

Your models will then look like the following.

```
class Artist < ApplicationRecord
has_many :event_artists
has_many :events, through: :event_artists

class Event < ApplicationRecord
has_many :event_artists
has_many :artists, through: :event_artists

class EventArtist < ApplicationRecord
belongs_to :artist
belongs_to :event
```

To add a Users table into the mix, you must create `UserArtists` and `UserEvents`.

**Note**: Table names such as `UserArtists` could be instead be named `Follows` - it all depends on what you think is clear.

Comment: This is kinda right i believe, A user can not be an artist, I never stated a use roculd be an artist, I believe i would have to make 3 tables, `eventsartists` `userevents` and `userartists`

Comment: Correct. For artists being users, I assumed since they are followed that they would manage their own accounts. But either way works.

Comment: The only problem i have with this, i'm trying to get the event the artist is related to and i cant seem to? i get `uninitialized constant Artist::EventArtist`

Comment: Do you have a repository where I could see the code?

Comment: I don't unfortunately due to reasons i can't explain :)

Comment: When you created the EventArtist model, did you use 'rails g model EventArtist artist:references event:references'? Your error is probably a naming or setup issue, but it's hard to tell without seeing some code. Maybe use JSFiddle.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168233/discussion-between-sam-roberts-and-philatanus).